# NSURLCache not working after iOS app termination

Tags: ios, caching, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache, nsurlrequestcachepolicy

I am building an app in which I am implementing offline mode as well. For this I used NSURLCache mechanism. When the app is in foreground then the cache mechanism works perfectly even if the device goes in offline mode. The problem comes when I quit the app and then open it in offline mode. This time NSCachedURLResponse is returning nil for the particular request.

Below is the code I am using for this:

**Custom Cache Creation:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURLCache *urlCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:1024*1024 diskCapacity:1024*1024*5 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:urlCache];
}
```

**Calling server and cached object:**

```
-(void)serverCall
{
   NSURLCache *urlCache = [NSURLCache sharedURLCache];

   NSString *urlString = nil;
   NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
   NSError *error = nil;

   urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BASE_URL,url];
   urlString = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

   NSURL *finalUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:finalUrl];
   request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;

   NSData *data = nil;

   if ([self checkInternetConnection])
   {
       data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

       NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:data];
       [urlCache storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];
   }
   else
   {
       NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [urlCache cachedResponseForRequest:request];
       response = cachedResponse.response;
       data = cachedResponse.data;
   }
}
```

I can see that caches.db in library path of application the response is saved. But when i am trying to read it in Offline mode (after app is killed from background), the cached response is coming nil. I have gone through following links (and many more) but couldn't find the solution of my problem.

[NSURLCache Problem with cache response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338171/nsurlcache-problem-with-cache-response)

[How to use NSURLCache to return cached API responses when offline (iOS App)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705709/how-to-use-nsurlcache-to-return-cached-api-responses-when-offline-ios-app)

http://twobitlabs.com/2012/01/ios-ipad-iphone-nsurlcache-uiwebview-memory-utilization/

http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/

[Bypassing http response header Cache-Control: how to set cache expiration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840688/bypassing-http-response-header-cache-control-how-to-set-cache-expiration)

I have checked the http header fields and cached header in the api response and the problem is not from server end.

I have also tried providing a path in diskPath param while creating the custom cache but then it doesn't even load the cached object while the app is in foreground and internet disconnects. I have also changed the expiration date but the working is still same.

I have tried using SDURLCache but I am facing the similar problem. However I have successfully achieved this with ASIHTTPRequest but I don't want to use it as I have written all the server operations once already and I have to change every request with ASIHTTPRequest method.

Please help me find a solution for this. 
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Are you able to fix this problem? I am also giving same issue. Data is there in cache.db but its not loading and if you reload app multiple times it will sometimes load data. That's weird.

Comment: @Arsalan No, I wasn't able to find an solution. At that time I used ASIHTTPRequest to achieve this. Thought I am still facing the same issue while using NSURLCachePolicy.